# Graph adjacenct matrix and list bug

Tags: c, graph

I am doing a graph, my graph with only the adjacent matrix works fine, with the adjacent list it became buggy, changing value of the `adjmtx[3][2]` to a random number:

```
Graph* graph = createGraph(4);
Graph* graph = createGraph(3);
```

These seem to work, but this:

```
Graph* graph = createGraph(5);
```

causes a  crash.  What I don't understand is when I debug everything functions well.  What can it be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int num;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct Graph{
    int nodes;
    int** adjmtx;
    Node** adjlist;
}Graph;

Node* createHead(){
    Node* head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

Node* createNode(int num){
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->num = num;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void addAdjlist(Node* head, int num){
    Node* node = createNode(num);
    while(head->next != NULL && head->next->num < node->num){
        head = head->next;
    }
    node->next = head->next;
    head->next = node;
}

Node** createAdjlist(int** adjmtx, int nodes){
    Node** adjlist;
    int i, j;
    adjlist = malloc(sizeof(Node*));
    for(i=0 ; i<nodes ; i++){
        adjlist[i] = createHead();
        for(j=0 ; j<nodes ; j++){
                if(adjmtx[i][j] != 0)
                    addAdjlist(adjlist[i],j);
        }
    }
    return adjlist;
}

int** createAdjmtx(int nodes){
    int** adjmtx, i, j;
    adjmtx = malloc(sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0 ; i<nodes ; i++)
        adjmtx[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
    for(i=0 ; i<nodes ; i++){
        for(j=0 ; j<nodes ; j++)
            adjmtx[i][j] = 0;
    }
    for(i=0 ; i<nodes ; i++){
        for(j=i ; j<nodes ; j++){
            if(i!=j){
                printf("[%d]-[%d]",i,j);
                scanf("%d",&adjmtx[i][j]);
                adjmtx[j][i] = adjmtx[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return adjmtx;
}

Graph* createGraph(int nodes){
    Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof(Graph));
    graph->nodes = nodes;
    graph->adjmtx = createAdjmtx(nodes);
    graph->adjlist = createAdjlist(graph->adjmtx,nodes);
    return graph;
}


void viewAdjmtx(int** adjmtx,int nodes){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0 ; i<nodes ; i++){
        for(j=0 ; j<nodes ; j++){
            printf("%d\t",adjmtx[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void viewAdjlist(Node** adjlist,int nodes){
    int i;
    for(i=0 ; i<nodes ; i++){
        printf("[%d]:",i);
        while(adjlist[i]->next != NULL){
            printf("%d -> ",adjlist[i]->next->num);
            adjlist[i] = adjlist[i]->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
}
int main(){
    Graph* graph = createGraph(4);
    viewAdjmtx(graph->adjmtx,graph->nodes);
    viewAdjlist(graph->adjlist,graph->nodes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your code. A pointer is not an array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not allocating enough memory for your data structures.

```
adjmtx = malloc(sizeof(int*));
for(i=0 ; i<nodes ; i++)
    adjmtx[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));

....

adjlist = malloc(sizeof(Node*));
```

You only allocate enough memory for one entry instead of `nodes` entries, so you're writing past the bounds of your allocated memory, resulting in undefined behavior.

Allocate `nodes` entries for each:

```
adjmtx = malloc(nodes * sizeof(int*));
for(i=0 ; i<nodes ; i++)
    adjmtx[i] = malloc(nodes * sizeof(int));

....

adjlist = malloc(nodes * sizeof(Node*));
```

Also, be sure to `free` up your memory in `main` when you're done with it.

Comment: Very thank you dude, two weeks with something simple like that.